# Как в Regex в качества аргумента передать массив?

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, как в Regex передать массив
Я попытался, но компилятор выдает ошибку

Regex regex = new Regex(keywords);

Comment: почему вы решили, что Regex должен этот массив принять?

Comment: я создал массив строк  keywords и хочу, чтобы Regex находил все "слова" в тексте, которые есть в массиве

Comment: для этого вам надо 1) Составить нужное регулярное выражение 2) Отправить его в конструктор Regex. Regex работает только с регулярными выражениями, со всем, что не регулярное выражение, Regex не работает

Comment: Вы все пытаетесь регулярками разбор исходника сделать?

Comment: да, создать анализатор кода для меня пока сложновато

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже было сказано - создать объект класса `Regex` из массива Вам не удастся (не поддерживает его конструктор такую сигнатуру, это и очевидно!).

Если Ваша задача звучит так:

> хочу, чтобы Regex находил все "слова" в тексте, которые есть в массиве

то Вам действительно необходимо сначала Ваш массив слов преобразовать в строку *регулярного выражения*:

```
static string GenRegexStr(string[] words){
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            strBuilder.AppendFormat("({0})|", word);
        }
        strBuilder.Length--; //убираем последний "|" 

        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Дальше уже дело за малым:

```
var elements = new string[] { "text", "lorem" };
var regexStr = Program.GenRegexStr(elements);
var regexp = new Regex(regexStr);
var matches = regexp.Matches("lorem ipsum test text bla bla bla");

foreach(Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Результат:

```
lorem
text
```